# Google Analytics in AngularJS. Cannot see real-time page viewing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I'm adding Google Analytics to an AngularJS application that I have. For some reason it is not working, but I believe my code is correct.

I included this script at the bottom of the head tag:

```
<!--Google Analytics-->
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
</script>
```

I am testing this on localhost, so the 'auto', should work.

This is the code in my module:

```
angular
  .module('myModule')
  .run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$window', function($rootScope, $location, $window){
      $rootScope
          .$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
              function(event){

                  if (!$window.ga)
                      return;

                  $window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: $location.path() });
              });
  }]);
```

I have made sure that this runs every time the page is changed. And I am not getting any errors, but when I go into my analytics, I don't see anything in the real-time tab. Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: try $locationChangeSuccess event, it worked for me

Comment: The $stateChangeSuccess works just fine. When I console.log something in it, it prints out every time I go to a new page, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a SPA? 
Try using the target state url (or name):

```
.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
          function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

              if (!$window.ga)
                  return;

              $window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: toState.url });
          });
```

Remember GA will discard track requests depending on window time from the same page and IP.

Comment: Oh does it? Well then that's very helpful information. I'll test and see if it's because I'm running on the same IP. If that's the reason, I'll be sure to select your answer as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use GA 'set' to ensure routes are picked up for Google realtime analytics. Otherwise subsequent calls to GA will not show in the realtime panel.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    $window.ga('set', 'page', $location.url());
    $window.ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

Google strongly advises this approach instead of passing a 3rd param in 'send'.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to implement Google Tag Manager on your single page application and fire Google Analytics Pageview tag on gtm.historyChange event. Here is guide for Google Tag Manager v.1:

https://moz.com/blog/recover-lost-pageviews-in-pushstate-experiences

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution to see all my clicks in the real time overview is this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    if ($window.ga != undefined) {
        $window.ga('set', 'location', window.location.origin + window.location.pathname);
        $window.ga('send', 'pageview');
    }
});
```

But I have no idea if sending **location** parameter instead of **page** parameter is correct from the reports perspective.